# Where to obtain the token to register a GitLab runner?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab repository.
I want to add a runner to it.
I was able to install it, with the instruction [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html) without Docker (step 3).

Now I have to register it according to the instructions [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/). In the beggining of that file it is wrriten that I have to obtain a token, but I don’t understand where do I obtain the token from.

In [this link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/) it is wrriten that
I can get the token from `CI/CD -> settings`
but `CI/CD` does not have a `settings` option.

Also, in the registration instruction in step 2, it is written:
`Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL` but there is no documentation anywhere about what is this URL

Answer (score 2):

For a specific GitLab runner tied to a project, the token can be found in Step 3; in `Project -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Runners` in the `Setup a specific Runner manually` section.

You will also be able to find the URL which you need to use to register the runner in Step 2.

[image: Runner configuration]

Comment: I don't see Runners in the CI/CD section. Do I need special permissions for that?